# ffmpeg - overlay multiple gifs and pngs and generate a new gif

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I have a list of inputs (a combination of gifs and png) that I am trying to overlay and create a new gif. I was able to achieve this using this command and the following result:

```
_ffmpeg
    .withOptions([
        '-ss 1',
        '-i animated.gif',
        '-i base-goldfish.png',
        '-i eyes-wink.gif',
        '-i mouth-pleased.png',
        '-i palette.png',
        '-filter_complex [0][1]overlay[i1];[i1][2]overlay[i2];[i2][3]overlay',
        '-f gif',
    ])
    .output('./res.gif')
    .on('start', console.log)
    .on('error', console.error)
    .run();
```

As you can see, the result is very grainy. I have then generated a `palette.png` with the hopes of improving the quality.

However I struggle to find the syntax to use `complex_filter` to combine an overlay and a palette. Does someone know?

*ps1: I also tried to generate an mp4 (with good quality) and then convert it to .gif, but the result is identically bad.*

*ps2: I used gifski to convert the mp4 to gif with good success. But i'd like to avoid introducing a new dependency.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031)

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i animated.gif -i base-goldfish.png -i eyes-wink.gif -i mouth-pleased.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=format=auto[i1];[i1][2]overlay=format=auto[i2];[i2][3]overlay=format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" output.gif
```

`format=auto` was added to each [overlay filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) to improve quality of the overlay.

Comment: What does `split[s0][s1]` represent?

Comment: @Gregory [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031) says "split filter will allow everything to be done in one command and avoids having to create a temporary PNG file of the palette". `[s0][s1]` are arbitrary names given to the outputs from the split filter.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command I ended up with:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1 -i animated.gif -i base-goldfish.png -i eyes-wink.gif -i mouth-pleased.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=format=auto[i1];[i1][2]overlay=format=auto[i2];[i2][3]overlay=format=auto,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen=stats_mode=single[p];[s1][p]paletteuse=new=1 output.gif
```